# Simplifying Ampère force law for two separate closed wires

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

The force experienced by one closed circuit over another in magnetostatics is given by the Ampère Force Law:

In the particular case of considering two closed complete circuits  $C_1$ and $C_2$, the following expression can be simplified expanding the triple product.

$$\begin{aligned} \vec{F}_{12} & = \frac{\mu_{0}I_{1}I_{2}}{4 \pi} \oint_{C_{2}} \oint_{C_{1}} \frac{ \vec{dl}_{2} \times\left( \vec{dl}_{1} \times \hat{R}_{12}\right)}{|R_{12}|^{2}} = \\[1em]
& = \frac{\mu_{0}I_{1}I_{2}}{4 \pi}\oint_{C_{2}} \oint_{C_{1}} \frac{ \left(\hat{R}_{12}\vec{dl}_{2}\right)\vec{dl}_{1} }{|R_{12}|^{2}}-\frac{ \left(\vec{dl}_{1}\vec{dl}_{2}\right)\hat{R}_{12} }{|R_{12}|^{2}}
\end{aligned}$$

Note that $R_{12}=|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|$ is the difference between the position vector of the circuits.

Applying Stoke's Theorem over the first member of the expansion of the triple product:
$$\begin{aligned} \oint_{C_{1}} \frac{ \left({dl}_{2}\hat{R}_{12}\hat{dl}_{2}\right)}{|R_{12}|^{2}}\vec{dl}_{1} & = \int_{S_{1}} \left(\nabla \times \left(\frac{ {dl}_{2}}{|R_{12}|^{2}}\right)\right)\left( \hat{R}_{12}\hat{dl}_{2}\right)\vec{n}_1{dS}_{1} \\[1em] & + \int_{S_{1}} \left(\nabla \times \left( \hat{R}_{12}\hat{dl}_{2}\right)\right)\left(\frac{ {dl}_{2}}
{|R_{12}|^{2}}\right)\vec{n}_1{dS}_{1}\end{aligned}$$

The first term is zero because $dl_2$ does not depend on the point coordinates of $\nabla$ as we are integrating in $S_1$. Nevertheless, I can't see why the second term is zero or if it is at all.

I know that the integral has to be zero because the force can be simplified to $$\vec{F}_{12}=-\frac{\mu_{0}I_{1}I_{2}}{4 \pi} \oint_{C_{2}} \oint_{C_{1}}\frac{ \left(\vec{dl}_{1}\vec{dl}_{2}\right)\hat{R}_{12} }{|R_{12}|^{2}}$$